# What SQL query can I run to remove all users assigned to a particular group?

Tags: users, permissions, mysql

So I have a user group containing a few thousand users and I want to remove all of those users with a SQL script.

These users don't have access to the control panel and so don't have any Entries authored by them.

At the moment I have this:

```
DELETE FROM elements WHERE id IN (SELECT userId FROM usergroups_users WHERE `groupId` = 5);
```

It looks like this removes related entries from the `users`, `usergroups_users` and `content` tables by virtue of the foreign key/cascade constraints.

Is there anything else I need to clean up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done it the correct way.  Assuming all of Craft's foreign keys and cascading deletes are all still in place, removing the user's element ID from the `craft_elements` table is the way to go and all related data will cascade delete from there.